# Expo React Native project showing this error while running on iOS simulator

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-hermes

This error comes up while project was running in iOS simulator. On anrdoid emulator/ real device this project was running smoothly whitout showing any error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vlaiq.png)

ERROR  Invariant Violation: Your JavaScript code tried to access a native module that doesn't exist.

If you're trying to use a module that is not supported in Expo Go, you need to create a development build of your app. See https://docs.expo.dev/development/introduction/ for more info., js engine: hermes
ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes

I checked project name, slug name was same in package.json and app.json both file.
Also I had done cache clear process.

del node_modules
npm cache clean --force
npm install
watchman watch-del-all
del %localappdata%\Temp\haste-map-*
del %localappdata%\Temp\metro-cache
expo start --clear